# Does a helmholtz resonator have a standing wave inside the volume at the resonant frequency?

Tags: acoustics

If one were to exercise a resonator at the resonant frequency and you were able to measure the pressure at all points within the volume at a particular moment in time would the pressure be uniform at all points within the volume or would there be points where the pressure was more than other points? If it is not uniform and you graphed the pressure within the volume would it appear to be a standing wave within the vessel?

To me it seems like it would need to be a pressure wave and it seems like it would be a standing wave but I am not a physicist so I thought I would ask one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standing wave (with nodes and antinodes). The wavelength does not fit inside the cavity. It is a mass-spring system, where the inertia is in the neck of the cavity and the springiness is provided by the air volume.
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/cavity.html

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could have done the calculation to see that it does not fit...